# Using linq to find duplicates in List<Vector2>

Tags: c#, linq, unity-game-engine

I have a List, and would like to use Linq to find all duplicates in this list. I understand that the following solution works for strings and other types, but it apparently doesn't work for Vectors. Thoughts?

```
list.GroupBy(x => x)
.Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
.Select(g => g.Key)
.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should group by (and select) X and Y property from your Vector2.

```
list.GroupBy(x => new {x.X, x.Y})
.Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
.Select(g => new {g.Key.X, g.Key.Y})
.ToList();
```